# Cartalyst Sentry2 only one user can log in

Tags: laravel, laravel-4, cartalyst-sentry

I'm using Cartalyst Sentry2 authentication in my Laravel 4.0 application.

For some reason, I can only log in only one time with an account.  If I tried to login again with another browser or another computer, the other session get log out automatically.

I am wondering if this is a feature of Sentry2 and how I can disable it.

### Edit

Multiple Login Instances for the same user github feature request

https://github.com/cartalyst/sentry/issues/261

Comment: That's a feature, a good feature in my opinion ;)

Comment: Haha, it's not a bug, it's a feature! http://www.buzzfeed.com/lukelewis/28-things-only-developers-will-find-funny?sub=2460354_1416162

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is a feature.

..and Nico Kaag answered the question here: [Laravel: Enable Sentry user account be used in multiple computers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17393833/laravel-enable-sentry-user-account-be-used-in-multiple-computers)